# how to convert json dataframe to other dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have download stock data by json, and i want to convert this data to other data frame... I am using Python 2.7.15... I am not programmer.

My code is like this:

```
import requests
import pprint
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

function = "TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED" # Date, Open, High, Low, Close,     Volume, Adjusted close, Split/Dividend events

SP500_symbols=['MSFT']

api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"    #<-- goes here your API KEY

data = { "function": function, 
        "symbol": SP500_symbols, 
        "apikey": api_key } 
page = requests.get(url, params = data)
pprint.pprint(page.json())
```

My data looks like this:

[image]

And i want to see my data like this:
[image]

Comment: Don't post images of data or code, post as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the *demo-API* key:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"
params = {
    "function": "TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED",
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "apikey": "demo"}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = response.json()

def convert_response(d):
    # convert the response into datetimerecords that can be
    # parsed by Pandas
    for dt, prec in d['Time Series (Daily)'].items():
        r = { 'datetime': dt}
        r.update(prec)
        yield r

# pass your response 'page'
df = pd.DataFrame(convert_response(data))
# rename the columns    
df = df.rename(columns={ '1. open': 'Open', '2. high': 'High', '3. low': 'Low', '4. close': 'Close', '5. adjusted close': 'AdjClose', '6. volume': 'Volume'})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
# extract the columns you want
df = df[[ 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'AdjClose', 'Volume']]
print(df)
# or reverse order
# print(df[::-1])
```

Shows:

```
                Open      High       Low     Close  AdjClose    Volume
datetime                                                              
2018-07-13  104.3700  105.6000  104.0900  105.4300  105.4300  24578301
2018-07-12  102.7700  104.4100  102.7300  104.1900  104.1900  24335929
2018-07-11  101.1500  102.3400  101.1000  101.9800  101.9800  19644648
```

You can wrap it all in one function. In that case all the logic of the conversion gets isolated and you only call *df_from_response()*.

```
def df_from_response(data,
         columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'AdjClose', 'Volume']):

    def convert_response(d):
        # convert the response into datetimerecords that can be
        # parsed by Pandas
        for dt, prec in d['Time Series (Daily)'].items():
            r = { 'datetime': dt}
            r.update(prec)
            yield r

    # pass your response 'page'
    df = pd.DataFrame(convert_response(data))
    # rename the columns    
    df = df.rename(columns={'1. open': 'Open',
                            '2. high': 'High',
                            '3. low': 'Low',
                            '4. close': 'Close',
                            '5. adjusted close': 'AdjClose',
                            '6. volume': 'Volume'})
    df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
    df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    # extract the default columns
    df = df[columns]
    return df

df = df_from_response(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: I've added code that makes the request based on a demo API key, copy /paste and change your key and your are set

Comment: @yossi : if you copy /paste this snippet you simply run it and it will give you a dataframe 100 x 6 . Try that first pls.

Comment: Hi hootnot, it works (you make good job!). i am using now your code, but in my column of datetime, the dates looks like random. in your shows, it looks o.k....the first date is 2018-03-08, the second 2018-03-09, the third 2018-05-11, 2018-07-09, 2018-07-05, 2018-07-06, 2018-07-02, 2018-07-03, 2018-05-29, 2018-04-03, 2018-02-22, 2018-03-28,  2018-03-29, 2018-03-26....i don't see any reason to random in dates column.

Comment: @yossi I added a few lines possibly after you copied. Those lines create a sorted datetime index.

Comment: hootnot, You are a genius! Thanks.

Comment: @yossi, see extension

Comment: @yossi: if you consider this as an answer, pls. accept it as an answer, thx

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas read_json and then transform the Pandas dataframe.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html